# Setting CLASSPATH for Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and try to work with APIs. Couldn't understand how to do it with standard libraries so i downloaded Apache HttpClient from [this](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) website.
Extracted lib folder from the zip and tried to set CLASSPATH with `java -cp lib` command but it doesn't work. Later found that you have to specify main class, so i tried `java -cp httpcomponents-client-4.5.2 org.apache`. It didn't work either.

Installed Intellij IDEA and in Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies managed to set it right, just by choosing the lib folder, but  i want to make it work in Sublime Text and Android Studio.

How should i properly set CLASSPATH for external .jars?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. The httpcomponents-client is a programming library, not an executable. Are you asking how to set the java classpath in sublime text (which is not a Java specific IDE) and android studio so that you can compile code using httpcomponents library, or are you asking something else?

Comment: @kaliatech I want to set classpath for apache libraries so that i can just compile java class with `javac` and run with `java`. And yes i want them also to work in Android Studio and Sublime Text(as far as i understand, if i set classpath then Sublime would use it too).

Comment: Android Studio doesn't require you to mess with the `java -cp` command, so I'm tempted to remove that android tag...

Comment: @cricket_007 Then how am i supposed to add it to my Android Studio?

Comment: Learn to use Gradle...